base64 decode brings back weird characters
I know this question has been asked before (I searched across a ton of answers with no luck). So, I am finally just asking my own question with my own example.
I have a base64 string in a database. Here is the string:
base64:YW5vaXRoZXIgcmVwbHk=CgpNc2cgJiBkYXRhIHJhdGVzIG1heSBhcHBseS4gTXNnIGZyZXF1ZW5jeSB2YXJpZXMuIFJlcGx5IEhFTFAgZm9yIGhlbHAuIFJlcGx5IFNUT1AgdG8gY2FuY2VsLg==
I try and decode it using a simple base64_decode() and I get this strange result:
anoither reply��\�� �]H�]\�X^H\K�\����\]Y[��H�\�Y\ˈ�\HS�܈[��\H����[��[
I did an explode on the beginning of the base64: since it was obviously an indicator that it was stored that way. But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get rid of the trailing strange characters. I have gotten close by doing a urlencode(base64_decode($string)) but then that produces this long strange string:
anoither+reply%02%82%93%5C%D9%C8%09%88%19%18%5D%18H%1C%98%5D%19%5C%C8%1BX%5EH%18%5C%1C%1B%1EK%88%13%5C%D9%C8%19%9C%99%5C%5DY%5B%98%DEH%1D%98%5C%9AY%5C%CB%88%14%99%5C%1B%1EH%12%11S%14%08%19%9B%DC%88%1A%19%5B%1C%0B%88%14%99%5C%1B%1EH%14%D5%13%D4%08%1D%1B%C8%18%D8%5B%98%D9%5B%0B
And I have not been able to figure out how to get rid of the above trailing strange characters either. Anyway, any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks!

Is it possible that whatever made the base64 encoded string in the first place did it incorrectly?

Use your php installation to create a new encoded string, one that matches your expected output, put that in the database, then run your code again - do you get the junk chars? If no, the original string is the problem. If yes, your php is broken. I know which one my money’s on

"I have a base64 string in a database." But do you know what the original binary data was? It's unusual for base64 decoding to result just in plain text - otherwise typically it would be stored as text in the first place, without using base64 at all.

I think you have multiple base63 strings in there YW5vaXRoZXIgcmVwbHk= seems like a whole string, and so does CgpNc2cgJiBkYXRhIHJhdGVzIG1heSBhcHBseS4gTXNnIGZyZXF1ZW5jeSB2YXJpZXMuIFJlcGx5IEhFTFAgZm9yIGhlbHAuIFJlcGx5IFNUT1AgdG8gY2FuY2VsLg==  but the next part is garbled due to a wrong offset (i think). as @ChrisHaas mentioned - i would look closely at the code generating the string, and the code storing it in the database

If you split on the center =, too, and just do the last part you'll see the rest of the message: https://3v4l.org/j8QLe

@ChrisHaas that was very helpful. So, if the first part is fine, and the second part is fine (if I decode them separately) is there a reason I can't decode it at the same time? I am worried about exploding at the "=" sign as that could cause issues if a string is stored normally. Not sure how I would do that. Thanks!

you can only concatenate two base64 strings if there are no spacers (=) otherwise you end in this situation

@JoSSte is there a way to fix it for the wrong offset? I have no way of knowing how it was stored (this was done before I came along). So, I have some fields that are normal and then some fields that have items like this stuck in there. Is there a workaround I can do?

Again you would have to either make sure that your output is aware that there can be = in the middle, in which case they should split the string, and include the = in the first of the two strings, or modify the input to ensure that the bytes in the input string are divisble by the base64 chunks (not advisable) or add a spacing character like \t to the database

I'd start with trying to figure out what is making the data this way in the first place. Is there a bug that needs to be fixed there, or did someone just decide to use = as a delimiter. If the latter, I'd agree on a new format, and let's say it starts with base64v2:. Then write code to parse this new format, maybe code to create new data in this format, and then a throwaway tool that walks through the database and migrates everything to the new format.

No matter what, we factually know that the provided string is not valid base64 data. Writing something to handle buggy data is asking for trouble down the road. It is way better to nip this in the bud right now.

One last thing I'd throw out there is that the second parameter to base64_decode is $strict which defaults to false and means "invalid characters will be silently discarded". If you pass true, instead, the function would fail and return false. Honestly, I'm not really certain what the value of the default is in the modern world, and I hope someone writes an RFC to change it

Ypu have two base64 strings concatenated  in the same field...
You have a string YW5vaXRoZXIgcmVwbHk=CgpNc2cgJiBkYXRhIHJhdGVzIG1heSBhcHBseS4gTXNnIGZyZXF1ZW5jeSB2YXJpZXMuIFJlcGx5IEhFTFAgZm9yIGhlbHAuIFJlcGx5IFNUT1AgdG8gY2FuY2VsLg== which is garbled when decoded. the = is used to fill out when input characters do not split nicely into base64 chunks. They are ALWAYS suffixed to the encoded string.
YW5vaXRoZXIgcmVwbHk= decodes to "anoither reply"
CgpNc2cgJiBkYXRhIHJhdGVzIG1heSBhcHBseS4gTXNnIGZyZXF1ZW5jeSB2YXJpZXMuIFJlcGx5IEhFTFAgZm9yIGhlbHAuIFJlcGx5IFNUT1AgdG8gY2FuY2VsLg== decodes to
"\n\nMsg & data rates may apply. Msg frequency varies. Reply HELP for help. Reply STOP to cancel."
You need to either split the encoded string at the = or make sure that the input encodes the string proberly as a whole string and not as a concatenation of two seperate strings.
You may have other strings where there is no issue since the string lengths fit with the base64 chunks.
I would suggest reading a little about base64 encoding to understand the issue: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-base64-encoding/
Solving the issue
First we need to understand the base64 padding. Here are some strings and their base 64 counterparts:



String
base64




abc
YWJj


æbc
w6ZiYw==


abcd
YWJjZA==


abcde
YWJjZGU=


abcdef
YWJjZGVm


!abcdef
IWFiY2RlZg==



as is apparent from the above table, going from a single-byte character like a to a multi-byte character like æ can be enough for the maximal padding (==), as if there had been added a single character (as seen in the  case of abcd).Therefore, in order to split the string succesfully, you would first have to try splitting by ==, and if any of the parts contain =, split that part by that, and base64_decode the rest. when you get to a point where there are no = characters, you can safely run base64_decode on the remains.
If PHP's base64_decode starts casting errors based on the missing padding, you will have to re-add them before decoding.
Discalimer
I have not checked the php base64 decode function  - my analysis has been done in notepad++ with the mime tools plugin. that supports padded and unpadded base64 encoding (if you had unpadded encoding in php you would be in trouble, but enough of that).

This definitely looks like the way I need to go. But, how do I explode the string at just the "=" and not mess up other messages in the DB if they end with the "=="? I am worried I would screw up the others. Thanks!

@swhitlow i have provided the approach I would take as an update to my answer - i would still consider altering the input
